# Speech to text button in textbox on a webpage

Tags: html, speech-to-text

Is is possible to have a working Google speech to text button in a textbox on a webpage?

[image]

How can it be done?

Comment: It's possible, but most (all?) TTS I've ever seen use Flash (vomit)... as of now... there's no reliable text-to-speech program which all devices have that you could program against...

Comment: @ImportedNoob: He means Chrome's HTML5 Speach Recognition.

Comment: Oh... well that makes it easier. check this out: http://techcrunch.com/2009/12/14/the-unofficial-google-text-to-speech-api/

Comment: sorry guys, I meant speech to text (like on the google homepage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's an [HTML5 thingy](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input) ...

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" x-webkit-speech />
```

so, will only work in available browsers.

> Live code: http://jsbin.com/afifaw/3

[image]

Comment: Ohhh that's what was meant... that's *fancy*

Comment: added jQuery code to the example to fire up after speech recognition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***really*** crude implementation of TTS that you might find acceptable. It's going to need some tender love and care, but it's a starting point.

```
<p id="tts">The maximum number of characters, including punctuation marks and all spaces, that I can read is 100</p>

<a target="new" id="ttsLink" onclick="document.getElementById('ttsReader').src='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('tts').innerHTML)">  <u>click me<u></a>

<br/ ><br />
<iframe id="ttsReader" width="10" height="10"></iframe>
```

Comment: The maximum length of input that the google API will read is 100 characters, that includes spaces and punctuation.