# How to make speech webkit work in Chrome extension popup?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-extension, speech-to-text

A [simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959439/speech-to-text-button-in-textbox-on-a-webpage/7960098#7960098) like this

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtSearch" x-webkit-speech />
</body>
</html>
```

works correctly in an HTML page.

I am trying to use the same code in the popup of my Google Chrome extension. But on clicking the mic icon, nothing happens in the popup.

Are there some restrictions to use code like this for popups? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome, can you file an issue on http://crbug.com

Comment: Thanks @Kinlan, I had filed it - 102473. But I thought that a popup is same as an HTML page, any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It's being worked on, apparently, but I can't parse out from this any progress since Dec 15, 2011.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=97388

Answer (score 0):

The bug still hasn't been fixed it seems :
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=102473&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=102473

Furthemore, someone recommends to use the chrome speech input API :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.speechInput.html
but :
1. This API is experimental and requires Chrome to have the "experimental API" flag checked (which isn't by default).
2. I have tested it on a few OS, and it makes chrome 23 crash on Win XP, which is very annoying.