# x-webkit-speech and panel/detached_panel windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Found an interesting bug I think.
Make a simple html page with a speech to text input with x-webkit-speech, like this for exemple :

```
<html><body>
    <input type="text" id="speech" x-webkit-speech />
</body></html>
```

If you open it in chrome and you click the microphone in the input, everything works Ok.

Now, create a plain extension, with "permissions": ["tabs"], and in the popup script somewhere create a **panel** or **detached_panel** window pointing to the previous html page. For exemple :

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: "index.html",
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    focused: true,
    type: "detached_panel"
});
```

Now click on the microphone in the input : nothing happens, nada.

Is this a known bug ?

Also, I have tested with type="popup" or type="normal" and it works Ok, so the bug seems to be only on panel and detached_panel windows. Also, I have tried to put it in an iFrame inside the panel window but still doesn't work. Note that x-webkit-speech doesn't work either in the extenions bubbles.
Furthemore, I started using the experimental API proposed by Chrome, but they require the experimental api flag to be enabled, which the x-webkit-speech doesn't require.

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Panels are not enabled by default they have to be explicitly enabled using `chrome://flags/`, i guess it is the only reason where all properties are not shipped

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even if you set that flag to enabled, it doesn't work. Furthemore, it doesn't even work in a plain extension popup bubble.

Comment: Your R&D is correct, may be raise an issue at crbug.com, we can **star** issue and look for responses.

Comment: I think there is already an issue concerning this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963697/how-to-make-speech-webkit-work-in-chrome-extension-popup/14161650#14161650

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=102473&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=102473

I stared it.