# Shortcut directly to Voice Search in Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am helping someone recovering from an accident that makes it difficult for her to type and control the mouse with much precision.  I'm not familiar with scripting languages used within browsers but would like to know if the following is possible:

A keyboard shortcut or function key is pressed that will, 1) create a new tab and open google.com in it and then,  2) Automatically "select" the microphone to start Voice Search without the user having to either select it directly or use the "Shift-CMD-." shortcut so she can start talking in the search command with no further keyboard interaction.

The computer being used is a mac running OS X 10.8.x and the browser is Chrome.  I've searched for chrome extensions that do this but haven't been able to find any that would help.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thank-you.

Comment: Some related information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256299/x-webkit-speech-and-panel-detached-panel-windows)

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered programmable keypads? For someone with limited dexterity / precision these devices may offer the solution you require and simplify keyboarding by limiting the number of keys to a small subset mapped to specific functions.

This 24-key keypad offers complete programability, though some reviewers remarked it is complicated to program.
[http://www.amazon.com/XK-24-USB-Programmable-Keypad-Windows/dp/B003MB780E/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003MB780E)

A cheaper option, which may be simpler to program, is to look at keyboards with a few programmable hot keys. A benefit of this keyboard it that it can pair with 3 devices and works with Macs, iPad/ods, Win PCs, etc. So, if your friend is also having difficulty using a phone as well this could be a huge help.
[http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Bluetooth-Illuminated-Keyboard-Smartphones/dp/B0099SMFVQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0099SMFVQ)